# Very simple CSS and HTML setup: Why is my page showing random results?

Tags: html, css

For some reason, this page is going wild on load. And if I resize, (including moving back to original size), it all loads perfectly, as if it was already there. But until resize of browser window, I get blank screen.

Note: Random combinations will load, weirdly, for me, before the resize.

Anyone see my problem?

Ok here is the JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/grDvW/1/

THe images arent loading but you can even see that the image placeholders don't show up until you resize the js fiddle output window. At least the issue is consistent.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css"><title>GameMode | Minecraft</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="keyword">
    <meta name="description" content="description">
    <meta name="author" content="Jonathan Todd">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrap"><!-- begin wrap :: this will keep all of the stuff neat and in one place -->
    <div class="login-screen bg-dirt"><!-- begin login screen, background dirt :: sets up a background for the login and styles it with a dirt tile and holds all login elements -->
    </div><!-- end login screen, background dirt -->
    <div class="welcome-screen"><!-- begin welcome screen :: this will hold the elements within the welcome screen, mainly just a title and the two moving wall pieces -->
       <div class="wall-left"><!-- begin wall left :: must I explain this? It opens and closes with the other wall -->
          <img src="images/wall_left.png">
       </div><!-- end wall left -->
       <div class="wall-right"><!-- begin wall-right :: must I explain this? It opens and closes with the other wall -->
          <img src="images/wall_right.png">
       </div><!-- end wall right -->
       <img class="welcome-logo" src="images/logo.png">
       <img class="welcome-shadows" src="images/shadows_fast.png">
   </div><!-- end welcome screen -->
</div><!-- end wrap -->
</body>
</html>
```

And my CSS is very simple as well:

```
/* Style Setup */

    body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,form,fieldset,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-perspective: 6500;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
fieldset, img {
    border: 0;
}
address, caption, cite, code, dfn, th, var {
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
}
caption, th {
    text-align: left;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-size: 100%;
    font-weight: normal;
}
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
}
abbr, acronym {
    border: 0;
}   
.wrap, html {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
/* Style Start */
.bg-dirt { }
.login-screen {
    z-index: 0;
}   
.welcome-screen {
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.wall-left {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0px;
}
.wall-right {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    height: 100%;
    right: 0px; 
}
.welcome-logo {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 4;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.welcome-shadows {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: there is nothing to show except some images, create a fiddle of your html. what exactly you want

Comment: @RabNawaz I'm making a fiddle now; is there a way that I can direct a fiddle to look for images starting from my site's root directory instead of renaming each image?

Comment: try full path from your website

Comment: ok updated. JS fiddle shows same result. When you resize the viewing area of the fiddle, the image placeholders show up

Comment: updated your fiddle,http://jsfiddle.net/grDvW/2/ can see the images... now can you explain your problem

Comment: Ditto, seems to be working for me too, http://jsfiddle.net/grDvW/3/.

Comment: @RabNawaz Ok what did you change? That fixes the problem in the JS fiddle

Comment: @RabNawaz submit the answer with whatever change you made so I can accept it - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Could you try removing,

```
body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,form,fieldset,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  /*-webkit-perspective:6500;*/
}
```

Comment: Ok, nope. No change there. Exact same result.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to create a Fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net? The HTML is pretty much empty, so it really doesn't help with debugging.

Comment: Right, doing that now.